# Where can I write Parse Cloud Code functions for android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Is it possible to write a cloud code function directly into android studio? If not where could I write one? I can't find it on my parse dashboard

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Cloud code is only written in the express module of your app inside cloud/main.js file, you can create cloud functions there and call them from your android app.
Example:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getPosts", function(request, response){
  var query = new Parse.Query("Posts");
  //TODO: query constraints here
  query.equalTo("key",request.params.text);
  query.find().then(function(results){
    response.success(results);
  });
});
```

and you can call this function from android as below:

```
public static void getPosts(String text, final onSearch onSearch) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("text", text);
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getPosts", hashMap, new 
        FunctionCallback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Post> object, ParseException e) {
                //TODO: use search results...
            }
        });
    }
```

you can see other cloud functions and parameters in the docs: [Cloud Code Guide](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide)

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply, where is the cloud/main.js file? I can't find it within my SDK, I have all the Parse libraries synced in my gradle

Comment: I haven't deployed any parse server code, just connected a parse server to my android app, I'm not sure where I can write cloud code and deploy it to

Comment: Where is your server located then, you can't just connect to it..
Did you use heroku or back4app or amazon aws?

Comment: I used amazon aws

Comment: if you didn't install the CLI follow [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-windows.html) link, if you have it installed pull the code using this line of code using your github link :
**git clone git@github.com:aws/aws-cli.git**

Comment: old docs covering cloud code at  https://web.archive.org/web/20151022201841/https://parse.com/docs  you could review this and then check how the CCode changed when parse PAAS was terminated ( you have to host it yourself on AWS etc... )   https://blog.gonimbly.com/how-to-migrate-from-parse-part-3-migrating-the-code-a2150bb8dfec

Comment: you can't use any of the cloud code implementation on that old documentation, it used Parse.com-CLI and parse is off now.

Comment: I am not familiar with aws but you must clone the repository of the code to your local machine using git commands

Comment: Can you provide more information about what is installed on your system, this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/how-to-set-up-parse-server-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) might help you.

Comment: Hello I now understand how to upload code to EB thanks to that link, however whenever I type an "eb" command in the cmd it says "eb is not recognised as an internal and external command". I have added all the paths to my environment variables as suggested too.

Comment: Additionally, does the code I upload to eb automatically sync with any servers I have running on parse?

Comment: hello I realise now that using the CLI is unnecessary as you can just do it through AWS dashboard. I'm now trying to use webhooks on parse to connect to the cloud code that ive set up whenever an object is saved

Comment: I am unsure of how to get access to the Parse.Cloud framework however. I've downloaded visual studio code and tried installing Express through the command prompt however it keeps saying it is unrecognised

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the CLI is unnecessary for using parse but it's the auth token for amazon to let you download and upload your code to their infrastructure, and it's a must install for your system to recognize its cmd commands ...[Install Python, pip, and the EB CLI on Windows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-windows.html)

Comment: then run eb init to install your libraries locally it will ask for credentials, select your parse application and then after editing re-deploy your code using : eb deploy